# Using TeamCity, how to manually trigger a DEPLOY against a previously built and tested build run?

Tags: deployment, teamcity, continuous-deployment

Using TeamCity 6.5, I am trying to figure out how to setup a manual deployment for a specific build run if it's possible.

What I would like to be able to do is to take an already built and tested TeamCity run (only the artifacts needs to be deployed - this is not a web application or site) and call an MSBuild step to publish the artifacts to somewhere else.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you talking about choosing the version of artifacts from the dependency at the time you run the deployment config?

Comment: @mockobject: Yes, I want to choose the artifacts from a specific build run.

Comment: what are trying to build here. Java, Rails, .net ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do what you want by setting up `Artifact Dependency` between the configurations where you want to do the manual deployment and the one where you have the built artifacts.

Once you have setup the Artifacts dependency, click on the `Run custom build` ellipsis near the "Run" button for the configuration. Here you will have the `Artifacts dependencies` part where it will say the configuration that this configuration you are running is dependent on and will also have a dropdown list from which you can choose the particular version of the other configuration from which to get the artifacts. Click run from here to run your custom build.

See here for more details: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Triggering+a+Custom+Build

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking about this a bit backwards. What you probably want is a build configuration that takes the previously known successful build (in TC terms it has a snapshot dependency) and then runs a different build targeted at dropping the artifacts somewhere. Pretty easily done by switching the output directories in MSBuild.

Comment: In fact it is not necessarily the last successful build, it can be an older one. When you wrote about switching output dirs in MSBuild, that would suppose a new compilation and that is not what I want.

Answer (score -1):

The most "integrated" way I could think to do it would be to add a dependency to your deployment configuration that depends on the latest pinned build for the dependent configuration.  Then you just unpin any newer builds in the dependent configuration and pin the one you want and run the deploy...This is a bit kludgy and might not work very well if you depend on pinned builds for anything else in the dependent configuration.

The other built in way to do with would be to add an artifact dependency using a specific build number.  The drawback of this method is that any time you want to deploy a different build, you will need to be able to edit the artifact dependency build number by hand and then hit run.